# On dit "on ne peut rien faire" ou bien "on n'y peut rien faire" ?

Tags: expressions

Est ce qu'on dit :

> "on ne peut rien faire"

ou bien

> "on n'y peut rien faire"

??

Comment: On ne peut rien faire. On ne peut rien y faire. On n'y peut rien. Ces trois phrases sont correctes mais chacune ayant un sens plus ou moins différent, tout dépend de ce que tu veux dire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si aucun problème spécifique n'est identifié ou que la situation est floue, on peut tout à fait dire « *On ne peut rien faire* ».

Si un problème a clairement été identifié on dit en général « *On ne peut rien y faire* » (on ne peut rien faire/changer à cette situation). La tournure « on n'y peut rien faire » est aussi possible mais c'est soit un peu vieillot, soit relève d'un certain style, on ne l'emploierait pas dans une conversation aujourd'hui.

Il y a aussi la tournure « *On n'y peut rien* » que Laure mentionne. Celle-là laisserait plus facilement penser que « c'est la vie », « c'est comme ça que ça marche ».